# SSRS chart X-Axis show start and end date only

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have searched and experimented without any success till now. I have a line chart with date values on X-Axis. I would like to display only the start date and end date on the X-Axis. All other tickmarks and values should be hidden.

I see that there is an option to "Hide Start and End values" in the Chart properties. But how do I display only the Start and end date?

Any help appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following steps :-

- Go to Horizontal Axis Properties.
- In Axis Options, Select the Axis Type as Scalar.
- Deselect "Always include zero".
- In Minimum box type `[First(Sale_Date)]` and in Maximum box type `[Last(Sale_Date)]`.
- In Interval box type `=datediff("d",first(Fields!OrderDate.Value),last(Fields!OrderDate.Value))`

Please let me know if it worked.
Thanks.

Comment: That works good for scalar type. However, I would like to keep my Axis in "Category". Is it possible?